# laravel syntax error, enexpected ',' , expecting ';'

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I tried to fix this but don't know how

[image]

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.home')->extends('layouts.app')->section('content'),[
        'products' => Product::take(3)->get()
    ];
```

It said that the syntax is error,

> unexpected ',', expecting ';'

I'm newbie to Laravel so I couldn't write the correct syntax. Please let me know.

Comment: You already closed all `)` so you can't add a second paramter to any method. Check your `)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views), to pass variables to the view, you need to set the second parameter in the method `view()` as the array of data.

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.home', [
        'products' => Product::take(3)->get()
    ])->extends('layouts.app')->section('content');
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but after I open my localhost it says that the Class 'App\Product' not found

Comment: @m4rsy4 you need to set the namespace either at the top of your file with `use App\Models\Product;` (the namespace depends on where is your class and declared namespace in it)  or in the code